# How to remove WinThumbnails gnome extension

Tags: gnome, uninstall

I have just installed winthumbnails extension and unlike other extensions it can't be uninstalled via https://extensions.gnome.org/.
Is there some other way to uninstall because it really bothers me because it is inactive and just staying there occupying space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility in two location . check there

```
/home/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

&

```
 /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```